# Obtaining information about the application that owns the active window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard

I am sure it's something easy, and I am not looking to the right documentation.

I need to get information about the application that handles the active window. The code I need to write needs to intercept some custom gestures, and return to the application an event that depends from the application itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the `NSWorkspace` class from which you can get a dictionary with information about the `activeApplication`. That application usually owns the "key" window.

**Edit:** For apps targeting 10.6 or later, `activeApplication` is deprecated. Here's the new way to go:

```
NSRunningApplication *activeApplication = nil;
for (NSRunningApplication *app in [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]) {
    if (app.active) {
        activeApplication = app;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Method `activeApplication` is deprecated from MacOS 10.7. Documentation suggests to use `NSRunningApplication` class.

Comment: @Saphrosit May you write that as answer?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Actually I think the answer is correct, just outdated, that's why I just put a comment. If you think it's better to add another answer I will :)

Comment: @Saphrosit I think the comment you wrote is perfect as answer. This question is tagged [tag:osx-snow-leopard], and the class you are referring is available since Mac OS X 10.6.

Comment: Seems funny to me that there's not simple accessor to get the active app. Updated answer to reflect updated API.

Answer (score 2):

Method `activeApplication` is deprecated from MacOS 10.7. Documentation suggests to use [NSRunningApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead.